# multisite environment in drupal using subdirectories on nginx

Tags: drupal, nginx

I'm trying to set up a multisite environment in drupal using subdirectories. There's a very good set of instructions here: http://www.drupalcoder.com/blog/drupal-multisite-in-subfolders, but it's specific to apache and I'm working with Nginx.

how do I do these 2 things in Nginx:

quoting from link above:

> **Add alias your Apache configuration file**
>
> We want requests for the 3 subdirectories to go to the same Drupal
>   instance. We can do this using Apache's Alias functionality.
>
> ```
> Alias /subdir1 /var/www
> Alias /subdir2 /var/www
> Alias /subdir3 /var/www
> ```
>
> I'm supposing here Drupal's codebase is hosted in /var/www on your
>   machine.
>
> **Redirecting all requests to index.php**
>
> Now that we're serving all requests from one codebase we have to
>   redirect all requests to index.php. This needs to be done since all
>   Drupal requests are served from one endpoint, called index.php.
>
> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdir1/(.*)$
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir1/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdir2/(.*)$
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir2/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdir3/(.*)$
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir3/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
> ```

Comment: I've tried both the below mentioned solutions but none of them worked for me. I'm struggling with the same issue!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work (did not check) for alias:

```
location ~ ^/subdir\d+/(.*)$ {
    alias /var/www;
}
```

and something like this for rewrites & fastcgi-php:

```
location / {
    root   /var/www;
    index  index.php index.html;

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite  ^(.*)$  /index.php?q=$1  last;
        break;
    }

    if (!-d $request_filename) {
        rewrite  ^(.*)$  /index.php?q=$1  last;
        break;
    }
}

location ~ .php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;  
    fastcgi_index  index.php;

    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING     $query_string;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD   $request_method;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE     $content_type;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH   $content_length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a map to capture everything after /subdir as a variable at the http level. Then you can avoid regex locations which introduce position dependencies.

```
map $uri $params {
    ~^/[^/]+/(?<subpath>.*) $subpath;
}

server {
    root /var/www;

    location /subdir1/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /subdir1/index.php?q=$params
    }

    location /subdir2/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /subdir2/index.php?q=$params
    }

    location /subdir3/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /subdir3/index.php?q=$params
    }
}
```